# I am failing to set datatable column width in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to display my item data in datatable, but some items have some really long strings in their description fields, so the whole datatable gets reaaaaaaly wide. I would like to somehow shrink the whole thing down but nothing seems to work. I already tried to use this:

```
div(DT::dataTableOutput("tableoutput"), style = "font_size: 75%; width: 75%")
```

and also tried adding `width = "XXXpx"` in the main panel, but the table is still too wide. I wonder if there is a way to somehow wrap long strings or set the column width?

Here is my code that brings me trouble:
UI

```
mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("textoutput"),
      div(DT::dataTableOutput("tableoutput"), style = "font_size: 75%; width: 75%")

    )
```

Server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
 observeEvent(input$selectinput, {
 selected_mod <- as.numeric(str_extract(input$selectinput, "(?<=\\]\\[)(\\d+)"))
    temp <- rvalues$fields[rvalues$fields$mod_id == selected_mod,]
    temp$mod_id = NULL
    temp <- temp[, basic_score:=as.numeric(basic_score)]
    temp$condition <- ifelse(as.numeric(temp$basic_score != 0), 1, 0)
    output$tableoutput <- DT::renderDataTable(
      DT::datatable(temp, options = list(paging = FALSE,
                                         searching = FALSE,
                                         columnDefs = list(
                                           list(targets = 6,visible = FALSE)
                                           )))
      %>% formatStyle(
        'basic_score', 'condition',
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('red', 'green'))
      )
})
}
```

Comment: have you looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666677/jquery-datatable-set-column-width-and-wrap-text) it seems related, and might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can include few parameters in `option=` to set width and make other changes.

For example, following code excludes column 6 and sets width of cols 1 and 3 of mtcars to 50 px

```
     DT::datatable(mtcars, options = list(
      autoWidth = TRUE,
      columnDefs = list(list(targets = 6,visible = FALSE),
         list(width = '50px', targets = c(1, 3)))
    ))
```

see https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html for more details

Comment: Yeah but I get into trouble because I am not sure how to combine many different options, for example my code has an option to make one column invisible...
```columnDefs = list(
   list(targets = 6,visible = FALSE)
    )```

Comment: It should be few lists inside columnDef:

columnDefs = list( list(targets = 6,visible = FALSE),
                              list(width = '50px', targets = c(1, 3))    )