# Datatables.js not wrapping cell text

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My html

```
<div>
    <table id="lf" class="cell-border compact stripe wrap" data-page-length='25'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Response</th>
                <th>Timestamp</th>
                <th>Traceback</th>
                <th>Frequency</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
         <tbody>
            {% for issue in page_obj %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ issue.response_code }}</td>
                <td>{{ issue.unix_timestamp }}</td>
                <td>{{ issue.message }}</td>
                <td>{{ issue.frequency }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My js

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#lf').DataTable( {
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    info: false
} );
</script>
```

I'm getting output like below image. I want to wrap column 3 [traceback]
[image]

I tried adding wrap parameter in js too like below but still not working.

```
columnDefs: [
    {
        targets: 2,
        className: 'wrap'
    }
    ]
```

Comment: Where's your css definition of `wrap`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a class and then render it in **columnDefs** like this:

```
 columnDefs: [
            {
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return "<div class='text-wrap width-200'>" + data + "</div>";
                },
                targets: 2
            }
         ]
```

css

```
.text-wrap{
     white-space:normal;
}
.width-200{
     width:200px;
}
```

For more you can visit this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39741977/6029001